# Adjusted $R^2$ (R-squared) for multivariate regression

Tags: regression, r-squared, multivariate-regression

For **univariate** or single independent variable regressions, this formula can be used ([details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2)):

$$R^2_{adjusted} = 1- \dfrac{SSRes}{SSTotal}\dfrac{n-1}{n-p}$$

However, I cannot find a similar formula for **multivariate** or multiple independent variable regressions (but I did find that the number of degrees of freedom in a multiple regression equals n-k-1, where k is the number of variables).

Comment: How would you define $R^2$ for general multivariate regressions?  It wouldn't make much sense without simplifying assumptions, such as spherical covariances.  Although you *seem* to distinguish multivariate regression (multiple response dimensions) from multiple regression (multiple explanatory variables), your last remark casts doubt on that.

Comment: I’m with @whuber that it will be important to define an $R^2$ analogue for the multivariate $y$ setting; then we can discuss an appropriate penalty for including parameters. [A post of mine on Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/109504/73930) might help you in defining such an $R^2$ analogue. // Further, what do you hope to accomplish with the parameter penalty? In regression with a univariate $y$, the particular penalty comes from comparing unbiased estimators of the variances of two models. What do you want in the multivariate setting?